# Solr StandardTokenizer creates wrong numbers

Tags: solr, token, tokenize

I got a Problem with my Solr core and the StandardTokenizerFactory.
I need to create number dimensions but the StandardTokenizer creates the wrong numbers.

e.g. I'm searching for "spanplattenschraube 4,5 50".

In my Solr Admin analysis the Tokenizer creates from this the numbers "4.0", "4.5.0", "5", "50.0", "50"

So as a first Result I get a document that contains "spanplattenschraube 4,0" but not "spanplattenschraube 4,5".

How can I prevent the StandardTokenizerFactory from creating wrong numbers or is there a better TokenizerFactory for my problem?

Comment: Which tokens do you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a simple token factory for example

**solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory**

Creates org.apache.lucene.analysis.WhitespaceTokenizer.

Creates tokens of characters separated by splitting on whitespace.

Please read here for more information:
https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.StandardTokenizerFactory

If you need to implement more logic how to split words and etc you can use later

**solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory**

Combinations of **WhitespaceTokenizerFactory + WordDelimiterFilterFactory**